# Distributing open-source C# .NET code - what parts of the solution to check in?

Tags: c#, github, open-source

I'd like to check in some C# .NET code to a new repository I've created on GitHub.

Usually we code in PHP/Python, in which case we'd just check in all of the .php or .py scripts and be done with it.

For my C# project, there's all of these extra files:

- .sln
- .csproj
- obj/
- bin/

To make this useful to other people, do I check all of those files in too? Or are these files specific to my computer, and shouldn't be in git/svn?

Answer (score 0):

The gitignore file will usually be set up to ignore the obj/ and bin/ folders but you should upload the .sln which is the solution file and the .csproj which is the project file.

On github you can automatically create a .gitignore file based on the language you have coded in.

Answer (score 0):

I think, yes, you should check-in *.sin and *.csproj files.
Pay attention that, these file are xml based files. when you add any other new item, you need to check-in these files too.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub has reasonable .gitIgnore for .NET

key files I tend to ignore

```
# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.sln.docstates
*.sln.cache

[Bb]in
[Oo]bj

localConnectionStrings.config
```

The [localConnectionStrings.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is good for websites where you can set web.config like:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="localConnectionStrings.config" />
```

This stops everyone overwriting everyone else's local dev database connection string when they commit (if that's how you work).

If you are not committing the bin folder, setting [Nuget Package Restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore) is useful too.